# Javascript Regular Expression to match six-digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to incorporate a regular expression i have used in the past in a different manner into some validation checking through JavaScript.

The following is my script:

```
    var regOrderNo = new RegExp("\d{6}");
    var order_no = $("input[name='txtordernumber']").val();
    alert(regOrderNo.test(order_no));
```

Why would this not come back with true if the `txtordernumber` text box value was a six digit number or more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert an extra "\" in your regexp.

Comment: This was the solution. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape your `\` when used inside a string.

```
new RegExp("\\d{6}");
```

or

```
/\d{6}/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your backslash. It's looking for "\d", not digits.

So...

```
var regOrderNo = new RegExp("\\d{6}");
```

Comment: Actually, it's looking for `/d{6}/`, not `\d` : )